# How to remove row in ListView using a SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I have three different activities sharing exactly the same layout (a ListView and a TextView). The ListView uses this layout for its SimpleCursorAdapter:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/locationName"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:text="Länsnamn"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/num_stores_row"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numStores_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="Antal butiker: ">
      </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numStores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="0">
      </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numItems_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="Antal artiklar: ">
      </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:text="0">
      </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

The program goes from activity #1, user picks an item in the list, activity #2 starts, user picks list, activity #3 starts.

Now, all the list items turn up fine just like they should, but for activity #3 I'd like to remove the entire row with id num_stores_row, and I seem to have a hard time doing this. I cannot do this in the setViewBinder since the row is not targeted by the adapter, and I cannot do it outside since the ListView is not activated until the data arrives. I've tried findViewById(R.id.num_stores_row).setVisibility(View.GONE); here and there, but the simulator crashes every time.

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to what Mark said, override SimpleCursorAdapter's getView and put your findViewById(R.id.num_stores_row).setVisibility(View.GONE);  in there once you inflate the row's view.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include that row in the `Cursor` that you wrap in the `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Or, create your own subclass of `SimpleCursorAdapter` that overrides a bunch of methods (e.g., `getCount()`) to filter out that row.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure what you mean. The only id:s included in the adapter (sorry for forgotting to paste the code!) is locationName and numItems. That is, the num_stores_row is already not included.

Comment: @bos: You are using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. This implies the existence of a `Cursor`. If your `Cursor` has rows in it that you do not want, you need to do a better job of creating the `Cursor` in the first place to not have those rows. So, you need to add to your `WHERE` clause to filter out anything you do not want in the `Cursor`.